# adding nodes to hadoop cluster virtualbox

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to setup a mini hadoop cluster with virtualbox:

hosts file (hosts file properly configured):

```
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/home/rui$ cat /etc/hosts | grep 10.
10.0.13.96 hnode1
10.0.13.97 hnode2
10.0.13.98 hnode3
10.0.13.99 hnode4
```

ip addresses properly configured (i manually edited the /etc/network/interfaces file, and as latter you can see I can ssh to the other machines)

```
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/home/rui$ ifconfig | grep "inet addr"
          inet addr:10.0.13.96  Bcast:10.0.13.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

ssh authentication without password to all nodes:

```
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/home/rui$ ssh hnode2
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

365 packages can be updated.
105 updates are security updates.

Last login: Tue Sep 23 10:52:52 2014 from hnode1
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:~$ exit
logout
Connection to hnode2 closed.
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/home/rui$ ssh hnode3
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

365 packages can be updated.
105 updates are security updates.

Last login: Tue Sep 23 10:52:59 2014 from hnode1
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:~$ exit
logout
Connection to hnode3 closed.
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/home/rui$ ssh hnode4
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

365 packages can be updated.
105 updates are security updates.

Last login: Tue Sep 23 10:53:04 2014 from hnode1
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:~$ exit
logout
Connection to hnode4 closed.
```

Slaves file defined as this:

```
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/etc/hadoop$ cat slaves
localhost
hnode2
hnode3
hnode4
```

JPS says nothing is ruining (either on master node and the other nodes)

```
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/home/rui$ cd $HADOOP_PREFIX
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1$ jps
3283 Jps
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1$ ssh hnode2
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

365 packages can be updated.
105 updates are security updates.

Last login: Tue Sep 23 10:53:46 2014 from hnode1
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:~$ jps
1834 Jps
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:~$ exit
logout
Connection to hnode2 closed.
```

next step i start the cluster:

```
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/home/rui$ $HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-rui-VirtualBox.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-rui-VirtualBox.out
hnode2: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-rui-VirtualBox.out
hnode3: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-rui-VirtualBox.out
hnode4: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-rui-VirtualBox.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-rui-VirtualBox.out
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-rui-VirtualBox.out
hnode3: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-rui-VirtualBox.out
hnode2: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-rui-VirtualBox.out
hnode4: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-rui-VirtualBox.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-rui-VirtualBox.out
```

and I do JPS and hadoop seems to running in both master and slave nodes

```
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/home/rui$ jps
2958 DataNode
3282 ResourceManager
3140 SecondaryNameNode
3411 NodeManager
2806 NameNode
3722 Jps
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:/home/rui$ ssh hnode2
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

365 packages can be updated.
105 updates are security updates.

Last login: Tue Sep 23 11:17:27 2014 from hnode1
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:~$ jps
2327 Jps
1889 NodeManager
1769 DataNode
hadoop@rui-VirtualBox:~$ exit
logout
Connection to hnode2 closed.
```

now when i tell my browser to go to hhttp://hnode1:50070
i see I only have 1 node alive

and when i tell my browser to go to hhttp://hnode1:8088/cluster
I also have one node available.

[image]

BTW hhtp://hnode2:8088 or hhttp://hnode2:50070 return unable to connect page om the browser.

Well, I should have 4 nodes, I only have one. What I am doing wrong?

I created one working virtual machine and then cloned the hard-drive and created new virtual machines and gave a different ip address to each.  However i did not re-formatted the hdfs (is this the problem?)

Then to master node (hnode1) I edited the slaves file (is this enough?)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution?